# SQL query in two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

TABLE:cities

```
city_id,  lat,  lon, name,  country_id
```

TABLE:countries

```
country_id,  name
```

I want a SQL query that returns:

```
cities.lat,  cities.lon,   cities.name,  countries.name(for the corresponding cities.country_id)
```

I swear this must be easy. But I can't get to make it work.

Comment: I suggest you read the basics of SQL...

Comment: Could you show your, however unsuccessful, attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join for this. Also always use alias of table name to understand easy and standard rule too.

```
select 
    ci.lat,  ci.lon, ci.name,  cn.name
from 
    city ci
inner join 
    countries cn on ci.country_id = cn.country_id
```

Comment: what is 'cu'? Undefined in your query ... select 
ci.lat,  ci.lon, ci.name,  cu.name

Answer (score 0):

If I got your point, this is the query.

```
SELECT cities.lat, cities.lon, cities.name, countries.name
FROM cities INNER JOIN countries
ON cities.country_id = countries.country_id
```

By the way, thought it is evident from the name that `cities.country_id` is referencing `countries.country_id`, you should have stated it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it using sub-query. But use the answer given by Ajay2707 and marc_s above. It produces the same result. I put my answer just for reference (sub-query) here :)

```
SELECT cities.name AS city, cities.lon, cities.lat, (SELECT countries.name AS country FROM countries WHERE countries.country_id=cities.country_id ) AS country FROM cities
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
   ct.name, ct.lat, ct.lon, cnt.name 
FROM
   cities ct, countries cnt 
WHERE 
   ct.country_id = cnt.country_id


[Using Join Keyword]

SELECT ct.name, ct.lat, ct.lon, cnt.name 
FROM cities ct
INNER JOIN countries cnt
ON ct.country_id = cnt.country_id;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: WHy has this answer been downvoted? Mr. Downvoter, can u kindly answer?

Answer (score -2):

```
select 
   a.name, a.country_id, b.cities, b.city_id, b.lat, b.lon, b.name 
from 
   cities b, countries a 
where 
   b.country_id = a.country_id
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. This here should use a proper `INNER JOIN` to join the two tables!!

Comment: @marc_s Sorry mar_c remember next time

Comment: I believe cities should have an alias a

Comment: Little bit changes please made, by the way you are developer